# ¿Qué sentido tiene que se pueda cerrar una pregunta en meta por estar basada en opiniones?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

Veo que a la hora de cerrar una pregunta en meta se puede cerrar la pregunta con la opción "se basa principalmente en opiniones".

Sin embargo, la mayor parte de las preguntas están etiquetadas con la etiqueta [discusión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discusi%c3%b3n), por tanto, son preguntas que ya se etiquetan directamente con el fin de que los usuarios opinen sobre la pregunta.

¿Tiene sentido este tipo de cierre de pregunta en meta? ¿Habría algún caso concreto en el que se debería de cerrar una pregunta con este tipo de cierre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respuesta adaptada de [Vote to close as “primarily opinion based” on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191774/182862):

---

La razón principal de que exista esa opción es que las razones de votos son estándares para todos los sitios de la red de StackExchange, meta incluido. Obviamente, algunas razones aplican mejor en unos sitios que otros y discutiría que la opción de voto de cierre basado en opiniones es menos aplicable a los sitios meta respecto a los sitios regulares.

Por otro lado, puede existir una pregunta [como esta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191770/145951) donde no solo era basada en opiniones, sino que las ideas expuestas no aportaban al sitio. En la mayoría de casos en meta, la idea es recolectar las opiniones de la comunidad y alcanzar una especie de consenso. La pregunta se refería no solo a un punto subjetivo, también era muy variable y no llevaba a una consecuencia. El resultado no sería sobre algo qué hacer ante una situación en la red de SE. Para el ejemplo citado, la pregunta pudo haber sido cerrada como No Relacionado por no haber encontrado un problema en un sitio de SE o similar. O simplemente ser votada en contra e ignorada como una pregunta inútil.

Mientras que la razón de cierre no es la más acertada, existen casos donde es la mejor y se puede cerrar una pregunta. En meta, sospecho que es muy rara una pregunta que realmente se pueda cerrar por estar basada en opiniones. [Esta pregunta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/16660) está basada en opiniones pero es apropiada para meta porque la decisión importa para el uso/moderación de un sitio de SE.

Comment: Por lo que veo, sólo en casos muy muy concretos se debería de usar este cierre.

Comment: Yo creo que este tipo de cierre es muy, pero muy inusual en meta. Aún así, puede darse.

Comment: Yo la verdad que ni me lo había planteado hasta que vi una pregunta etiquetada para cierre como "basada en opiniones". La verdad que daba por hecho que no existiera esta opción en meta. Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score -3):

Que cada valor puede ser subjetivo, lo que da pie a más discusiones que no lleven a nada.
Para eso están los comentarios

Comment: Sinceramente no entiendo a que te refieres con eso. Realmente hay preguntas que se hacen exclusivamente para que la gente de su opinión. Entonces, ¿qué sentido tiene ese cierre?

Comment: Por que según tengo entendido, stackoverflow es para dudas de cualquier tipo, no para debates de opinión, que o bien se realizan en comentarios, o en su defecto en salas de chat

Comment: Sí, pero me refiero solamente en torno a meta. El apartado de meta es para dar opiniones sobre cosas del foro que a la gente le intrigan. El 99% de las preguntas son pidiendo opinión.

Comment: @ras212 `stackoverflow es para dudas de cualquier tipo` no es del todo correcto, Stack Overflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas.